# Print `po` object description with println()?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, console

If I'm to do this:

```
class MyObject {
    var name = "Something"
}

var myObject = MyObject()
```

And then in the console at runtime, `po myObject`, I get this:

```
0x00007fe1596ef890
 (name = "Something")
```

In other words, it prints out the property values of every property in the object.

I want to replicate this behaviour using println, but doing `println(myObject)` just gives me:

> MyApp.MyObject

How can I get it to print out the property values, the same it would if I were to use the `po` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your class conform to the `Printable` protocol, a `description` computed property will be printed instead of the type name:

```
class MyObject: Printable {
    var name = "Something"

    var description: String {
        return "MyObject(name = \(self.name))"
    }
}

let myObject = MyObject()
println(myObject)
// MyObject(name = Something)
```

Alternately, you can use `dump()` instead of `println()` to dump an object's properties using Swift's reflection tools:

```
dump(myObject)
// ▿ __lldb_expr_920.MyObject #0
//   - name: Something
```